# How Do I Convert Horizontal Data Into Two Separate Vertical Tables With Conditions in MS SQL 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, unpivot

I have a sort of brute for solution for the following problem, but I'm sure someone here will have an elegant solution.

I have the following horizontally oriented table.

```
| Person  | Trait1 | Trait2 |
| Patrick | .3     | .4     |
| James   | .7     | .3     |
| Kristin | .9     | .2     |
```

I would ideally like to separate the above into two vertical tables based on the traits. There would be two vertical tables, Bad and Terrible.

If .4 <= Trait1 < .6 -> Bad,  Trait1 >= .7 -> Terrible

If .3 <= Trait2 < .5 -> Bad, Trait2 >= .9 -> Terrible

Using these conditions, we would then get the following tables

```
BAD
|Person   | Trait  | Value |
| Patrick | Trait2 | .4    | 
| James   | Trait2 | .3    |

Terrible
|Person  | Trait  | Value |
|James   | Trait1 | .7    | 
|Kristin | Trait1 | .9    |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using SQL Server 2005, you can use the UNPIVOT function to get the result.

The UNPIVOT takes the columns and converts it into rows which will be easier to apply your filter.

**BAD Data:**

```
select person, trait, value
into bad
from yourtable
unpivot
(
  value
  for trait in (trait1, trait2)
) u
where 
(
  trait ='trait1'
  and value >= .4
  and value < .6
)
or
(
  trait ='trait2'
  and value >= .3
  and value < .5
);
```

**Terrible Data:**

```
select person, trait, value
into terrible
from yourtable
unpivot
(
  value
  for trait in (trait1, trait2)
) u
where 
(
  trait ='trait1'
  and value >= .7
)
or
(
  trait ='trait2'
  and value >= .9
);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e04794/9).

Note, this can also be done using a UNION ALL query to UNPIVOT the columns into rows:

```
select person, trait, value
from
(
  select person, 'trait1' trait, trait1 value
  from yourtable
  union all
  select person, 'trait2' trait, trait2 value
  from yourtable
) d
-- where apply the filter here.
```

The UNPIVOT and UNION ALL converts the data into the following format vertical format:

```
|  PERSON |  TRAIT | VALUE |
----------------------------
| Patrick | trait1 |   0.3 |
|   James | trait1 |   0.7 |
| Kristin | trait1 |   0.9 |
```

Comment: Thanks bluefeet, I was actually going to do the union all but I like learning new functions like unpivot.

Comment: They do the same thing, when you have multiple columns to unpivot the UNION ALL has more code lines

Comment: Yeah, i am around 20 "traits" so i'm definitely going with the unpivot.